# How to plug info from one stored procedure to another?

Tags: c#, sql-server

The way this works, a drop down list has Price Groups in it and I need to get that Price Group and plug it into the stored procedure (`_getVendorDetails`) to get the Vendor ID. Then I need to put the Vendor ID into another stored procedure (`DIST_get_POShortagesaAndExtra_VendorIDNotes`) to get notes about the Vendor ID.

```
protected void LoadExtraVendorIDNotes()
{
    if (ddlVendorPriceGroup.SelectedValue == "NA") 
        return;

    DataSet ds = getVendorIDNotesPONotifications(ddlVendorPriceGroup.SelectedValue);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        lblShipmentScrutinyLow.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["ShipmentScrutiny"].ToString());
        lblContainsKitsLow.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["ContainsKits"].ToString());
        lblShippingIssuesLow.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["ShippingIssues"].ToString());
        lblMeetingNotesLow.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["MeetingNotes"].ToString());
        lblMeetingNotesLow.Visible = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["MeetingNotes"].ToString()).Length > 0;
        lblShipmentNotesLow.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["ShippingNotes"].ToString());
        lblShipmentNotesLow.Visible = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["ShippingNotes"].ToString()).Length > 0;
    }
}

protected DataSet getVendorIDNotes(string VENDORID)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MeyerConnectionString"]))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            dadapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("DIST_get_POShortagesaAndExtra_VendorIDNotes", objConn);
            dadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter vendorID = new SqlParameter("@VENDORID", VENDORID);
            dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(vendorID);

            dadapter.Fill(ds);
        }
    }

    return ds;
}

protected DataSet getVendorIDNotesPONotifications(string VENDORID)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MeyerConnectionString"]))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            dadapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("_getVendorDetails", objConn);
            dadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter vendorID = new SqlParameter("@pricegroup", VENDORID);
            dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(vendorID);

            dadapter.Fill(ds);
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Could you pull back a datatable linking price groups to vendors and vendor details. Then, when a price group and/or is selected you can extract the relevant rows? If your database is reasonably small, this would limit your database hits.

Comment: Create a variable to store the value of VENDORID and then pass it to your 2nd function/stored procedure. It seems like you do know how to do this already, so maybe you are not asking the right question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your example code it seems you are on the right track just that you need to invoke the `getVendorIDNotes` method from within the `getVendorIDNotesPONotifications` method and pass the `vendorID` to it.

The dataset returned from `getVendorIDNotes` is further returned from the calling method i.e. `getVendorIDNotesPONotifications` and hence the logic in `LoadExtraVendorIDNotes` should work as expected.